# Error 11001 while running a python code with Socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, web

I have been trying to run the python code attached below but I keep getting a error. Can someone tell me what's the issue or how can I solve it? Thanks!

Code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
        break
print data;

mysock.close()
```

[Error I get when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbinU.png)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Python\Programs\socket2.py", line 4, in    <module>
mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Please include the code and the exception traceback as text in the question (use the `{}` button for code formatting). It's impossible to copy and paste from an image, so not many people are likely to test out your code.

Comment: Alright! Done! @Blckknght

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. When I run your code (slightly modified to run in Python 3), it works just fine, with no exception raised. The exception message seems to suggest an DNS lookup failed. Are you sure the network of the system you're running the code on is working properly?

Comment: I uninstalled 64 bit version and installed 32 bit version of python and the code worked perfectly! This doesn't make sense to me tho since I have got 64 bit Windows 10! @Blckknght